# Spring MVC : How to Protect Application from CSRF and XSS

Tags: spring-mvc, xss, csrf

What is the best way to protect our Spring MVC application from CSRF and XSS.

Is there native Spring MVC support for this?

Answer (score 6):

In Spring:

Forms ( globally):

```
<context-param>
<param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Forms ( locally):

```
<spring:htmlEscape defaultHtmlEscape="true" />
```

Comment: Thank you @Abhi. And how about CSRF protection. Is there native support?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Spring Security 3.2.0.RELEASE and enable csrf support with this configuration

```
<http>
    <!-- ... -->
    <csrf />
</http>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a blog about it.

http://blog.eyallupu.com/2012/04/csrf-defense-in-spring-mvc-31.html

another one.

http://web.securityinnovation.com/appsec-weekly/blog/bid/79007/How-to-Prevent-Cross-Site-Request-Forgery-CSRF-in-SpringMVC

For token generation esapi can be used.
https://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/